# How to debug Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've sent a message to Google Firebase server. Got `success` response with `message_id`, but no notifications on my phone.
Is there a place on UI or CLI where I can put `message_id` and get status of message or some error message?

Comment: There's nothing in the console, but you can always have your app write back to a database if it got the message, so you could know if it was received.

Comment: thanks @Doug. So no way to debug wrong message format?

Comment: If you formatted the message incorrectly, I'd expect you to receive an error from the server immediately.

Comment: unfortunately not, got `success` :(

Comment: Did you find the solution? I got the same problem could you please share your solution.

Comment: Did you get further @AnatoliyKukul? Im stuck at the same place now

Comment: unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 0):

> Got success response with message_id, but no notifications on my phone.

“Success Response” from FCM just means FCM got your request, and will send it. It does not mean the message successfully delivered to the target device. However, it is possible that a message could be delayed, or even dropped, during this delivery.

eg.

1. Messages can be delayed or dropped if the device is not connected to the network.
2. Messages can also be delayed if the connected device is in [doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby) and your app's standby bucket is not high enough to [wake up the device](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/power-details).
3. ...

In terms of tools to help you debug, FCM provides three sets of tools to help you get insight into message delivery:

1. Firebase console message delivery reports(Go to Firebase Console -> Messaging -> Reports)
2. [Aggregated Android SDK delivery metrics](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/what-is-fcm-aggregated-delivery-data-d6d68396b83b) from the Firebase Cloud Messaging Data API
3. Comprehensive data export to Google BigQuery, where you can run sql queries in Google BigQuery to gain insights about the message delivery. [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android#message-delivery-reports)